# In Python if using *args do I have to limit number of args?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, args

I have a method that I'd like to give arguments via *args. I want to do this to keep the method veratile as it will be used for different things depending on the arguments passed.

What I want to do is have one method that sends requests to a webservice. 
The first argument is the call that should be requested and *args should contain the parameters to that call. Since different calls have different amounts of parameters checking the number of arguments passen for each call would be kind of cumbersome i guess.

If I use *args is it a problem if I don't check the number of passed arguments ?
Is it considered bad style ?

Example:

```
call_urls = {'getX': '?requestType=getX&argument1={}', 
             'getY': '?requestType=getY&argument1={}&argument2{}'

def makerequest(self, call, *args):
    url = ''.join([self.base_url, self.call_urls[call].format(*args)])
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)    
    return response      

result = api.makerequest('getX','blabla').read() 
print(result)
result = api.makerequest('getY','blublu', 'blibli').read() 
print(result)
```

As you can see I could easily pass another argument even though it will not be used for the call.

Comment: the way you handle arguments is wrong. You have to urlescape the parameters. Better use the requests-package for http-requests and transfer the GET-parameters by dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If some arguments are not used, the only side effect is that some bytes will be wasted. Well.. I do not see a problem with this.

The argument unpacking trick is intended to be able to receive any number of arguments. Logically, the passed arguments will be treated the same way, for example, in the `print` function - everything is printed. If you know all of the arguments and want them to be limited, just don't use it! Pretty simple, isn't it?